# Disable .NET in windows XP without deleting it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, .net-framework

I want to disable all .net come with windows but without uninstalling it.

There is `aspnet_regiis.exe -u` for some version, but how can I disable all versions and then re enable them?

Also, how can I re enable .NET after the `aspnet_regiis.exe -u` ?

Comment: after ` aspnet_regiis.exe -u` my IE closes itself very fast when I navigate it to `javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent) `

Comment: Why do you wish to disable .NET?

Comment: I need no .Net in my life and just want to live without it

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think disabling a .Net version makes sense if you have multiple .Net versions installed, and if the one you want to disable is not required by the OS.
But probably you need a restart.
The particular use in my case is to test if a new program will run on a lower .Net version than the highest version installed.
But probably this is exactly the same test as telling the program which .Net version to take.
Or isn't it? Filip

Comment: yoou do understand that the aspnet_regiis command is only useful if you are running a webserver, right?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "disable" .NET -- the CLR is a foundation component of Windows itself. You could uninstall it on Windows XP (not on later versions though, and only because Windows XP doesn't come with .NET in the first place), but that's the only solution. And many applications will simply cease to function without the runtime installed.

It should be noted that `aspnet_regiis.exe -u` does **not** disable the .NET runtime. It turns off ASP.NET support in Internet Information Services (which you should not be running on Windows XP anyway). .NET applications will still run even after that switch is applied.

Finally, I must point out that .NET is just like Flash or Java -- it's a foundation library required for many useful applications to work. There's really no reason to turn it off, any more than there is reason to ban all checkbox controls.

Comment: I ran the browser with flash (somtimes) and java (almost all time) turned off. I disable all extra plugins as acrobat reader and silverlight. The reason for it -- every programm have a exploitable bugs/ when I lower the number of programs which is used when I go to not trusted sites - I lower the number of exploitable bugs. I have 2 or 3 times when viruses installed on my machine after VISITING a trusted, but hacked site. It was "Flash exploit" called from pdf doucments, via Adobe reader plugin, which has own (older) version of flash plugin for swf embedded into pdf.

Comment: @osgx: Then you can disable the silverlight plugin in the browser. (Silverlight is the version of .NET that runs in the browser) It makes sense to turn that off. It does not make sense to turn off the entire .NET runtime, however.

Comment: but I also want to disable .net in the system

Comment: @osgx: You can't. And it doesn't make sense that you'd even want to. If someone is able to run .NET (NOT Silverlight, silverlight code gets sandboxed) code on your system, then they effectively already have control of the system. The only way .NET code ever runs is if you run a program written in .NET. And once that happens, the code has complete access to the machine, just as native code would have complete access to the machine.

Comment: @osgx: My point is: Why would someone bother to exploit the .NET Framework given that the .NET framework is *already designed* to give the .NET code complete access to the system? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: It makes no sense to want to disable it. Tinfoil hat territory.